# Append contents of each div to textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I have a list of divs created server-side, each with a price, quantity (entered by the user) and name. I've managed to use jQuery to calculate the total of each and add those up.

What I'd like to do now is to list the name, quantity and total of each item that has a value in my textarea, on a per-row basis.

So far I've got the following (the append part of which doesn't currently work):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".product-row input").change(multInputs);
           function multInputs() {
               var mult = 0;
               // for each row:
               $("div.product-row").each(function () {
                   // get the values from this row:
                   var $price = $('.price', this).html();
                   var $quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
                   var $total = ($price * 1) * ($quantity * 1);
                   // set total for the row
                   $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
                   mult += $total;
                   $('#textarea',this).append($name).append($total);
               });
        $("#total").html(mult);
    }
});
```

If I can get this worked out, I'm pretty sure I can work out how to add the grand total and clear the textarea each time something is changed (I'm not looking for someone to do all the work).

Any feedback as to why my textarea isn't populating would be very much appreciated.

Edit: The solution, really well explained below by braks has resulted in the following (working!) code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $(".product-row input").change(multInputs);

           function multInputs() {
               var mult = 0;
               // for each row:
               $("div.product-row").each(function () {
                   // get the values from this row:
                   var price = $('.price', this).html();
                   var quantity = $('.quantity', this).val();
                   var name = $('.name', this).html();
                   var total = (price * 1) * (quantity * 1);
                   // set total for the row
                   $('.multTotal',this).text(total);
                   mult += total;

                   $('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val() + ' ' + name + ' ' + total);
               });
               $("#total").html(mult);

            }

        });
```

Comment: `$('#textarea',this).val($name + $total);` - where is `$name` defined

Comment: past you `html code`  too

Comment: More detail is required here; why does it not work? What output are you expecting? Also, seeing your HTML would help a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(textarea).append(txt) doesn't work like you think. When a page is loaded the text nodes inside the textarea are set the value of that form field. After that, the text nodes and the value can be disconnected. As you type in the field, the value changes, but the text nodes inside it on the DOM do not. Then you change the text nodes with the append() and the browser erases the value because it knows the text nodes inside the tag have changed.

So you want to set the value, you don't want to append. Use jQuery's val() method for this.

You have to use something like `$('#textarea').val($('#textarea').val() + ' ' + $name + ' ' + $total);`

Except I'm not sure why you put $ in your variables, mix up with PHP ?

Comment: You're quite right about putting $ before my variables, d'oh! I'll have a play with this and post the results, thank you.